# Scope/context of anonymous functions/procedures

Tags: scope, tcl

This is one of those novice questions that arise for those of us who don't really understand the way things work in the background and get by for awhile thinking we understand; and, then, when encountering something new, we realize we didn't really understand what we thought we did.

I'm trying to make a function that is a do-while loop (to iterate a linked list by key sequence) that can accept a variable that is the loop body. My question has to do with passing the body script as a variable to another function/procedure.

In Javascript, I just pass an anonymous function. In Tcl, the scoping is different; I don't know what it is called but it is not lexical scoping. If I try an anonymous procedure, the variables that are in the anonymous procedure but not in the one to which it is passed, are treated as new variables in that procedure's scope. Therefore, I tried the `uplevel` `upvar` approach shown in Prof. Ousterhout's text and it works. And, I think I even understand it. But it appears the reverse of the way I've thought of it in JavaScript.

This tiny example, illustrates what I mean. In JS, I've always thought that I was passing the anonymous function to the other function (callee?) and it was executed in its scope. But, in Tcl, that thinking doesn't seem to work; for it appears that a variable name is being passed to the callee procedure to provide a loop variable in the callee's scope back to the context of the caller procedure, and the anonymous procedure is execute in the context of the caller.

My question is, in both Tcl and JS, in these example, is the `anonyProc` being executed in the context of `LoopBody` or is it really executed in the context of `Complex` and the loop counter from `LoopBody` is made available to it? Is there really a difference in what takes place in the code that processes the script or is it just two ways of writing the same thing?

I've one additional question specfic to Tcl, which is, Can this be done with an anonymous procedure and using `apply`? My first attempt is at the very end and the variable `value` is in the context of `LoopBody` rather than `Complex`.

Thank you for considering my question.

```
proc LoopBody {upvarName startKey endKey anonyProc } {
  upvar #1 $upvarName i
  for { set i $startKey } { $i < $endKey } { incr i 1 } {
    uplevel $anonyProc
  } 
}
proc Complex {} {
  foreach value {100 200 300} {
    LoopBody key 10 15\
        { 
          puts "key $key value [incr value $key]" 
        }
    puts ""
  } 
}
Complex

key 10 value 110
key 11 value 121
key 12 value 133
key 13 value 146
key 14 value 160

key 10 value 210
key 11 value 221
key 12 value 233
key 13 value 246
key 14 value 260

key 10 value 310
key 11 value 321
key 12 value 333
key 13 value 346
key 14 value 360
```

```js
function loopBody (startKey, endKey, anonyProc) {
  for( let i = startKey;
        i < endKey;
        i++ ) {      
     anonyProc(i);
  }
}

function complex() {
  [100,200,300].forEach( (value,key) => {
     loopBody(
        10,
        15,
        (x) => {
          console.log(`x: ${x} value: ${value += x}`);
        }
     );
     console.log('');
  });     
}

complex();
```

Failed anonymous procedure attempt.

```
proc LoopBody {startKey endKey anonyProc } {
  for { set i  $startKey } { $i < $endKey } { incr i 1 } {
    apply $anonyProc $i
  }
}

proc Complex {} {
  foreach value {100 200 300} {
    LoopBody 10 15\
        { { x } {
            puts "x $x value [incr value $x]"
          }
        }
    puts ""
  }
}

Complex

x 10 value 10
x 11 value 11
x 12 value 12
x 13 value 13
x 14 value 14

x 10 value 10
x 11 value 11
x 12 value 12
x 13 value 13
x 14 value 14

x 10 value 10
x 11 value 11
x 12 value 12
x 13 value 13
x 14 value 14
```

Comment: Your question needs to be more focused. (In particular you should focus on one programming language. Aside from anything else you want your question to be answered so making it impossible to fully answer by anyone who doesn't have expertise in **both** JavaScript and TCL is a bad idea!)

Comment: But the short answer: in LoopBody, you'll still need to uplevel: `uplevel apply ...`

Comment: And generally you want to specify the level without `#` -- `uplevel 1 blah` executes blah in the caller of the current proc; `uplevel #1 blah` executes blah in the first proc called from the global stack frame (which may not be this proc's caller). You can get the current level with the `info level` command. Same for upvar.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the warning about the `#.` I tried `uplevel 1 apply ..`. and cannot get it to recognize value as being from the caller's context. I tried using thisanswer also which is similar to that found in Ashock Nadkarni's text on Tcl. It works for a body only but when I try to pass the {params} {body} for an anonymous function, it either treats value as a new variable in the callee's context or errors that {x} is not a lambda expression

Comment: Sadly, you will to `upvar`. If you know the varname, you don't need to pass it: `upvar value value` will work.

Comment: @glennjackman I see, thank you. Having to `upvar` sort of the defeats the purpose because `LoopBody` shouldn't have to "know" anything about the variables in the argument passed as the body, apart from which variables relate to those of the loop counters. Using an anonymous function and passing a list of its variable names to be used in upvar in the callee doesn't seem to make much sense, unless I'm misunderstanding. If not, then that's probably why I could find an example in any of the texts I've been referencing. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I think using an "impure" anonymous proc (that has the side effect of altering a variable in a different scope) is tricky. Javascript's closures make that seamless, but Tcl's a different beast.

Comment: @glennjackman I wasn't criticizing Tcl but observing that  passing an anonymous proc and using upvar on its variables appears to provide nothing over passing a body and using upvar to connect variables from the callee proc to the body  (in the caller's context).. For example, using `upvar` on `key` when passing the body only, is just about the same as passing a proc that accepts an argumnet `key`. And you don't have to worry about the other variables in the body. From my limited perspective, it is more clear which variables are in which context than when passing a function in JS. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tcl, you need to think in terms of positions on the stack of stack frames. That is what both `uplevel` and `upvar` work with. There is no capturing of variables (that *can* be simulated, but both really is doing copies — that `incr` wouldn't work — and is quite a bit more complicated than what you have here). Lambda terms (the things you pass to `apply`) are just like procedures, except that the way that you specify their current namespace is different; most code that uses them leaves that at default (which is the global namespace).

Here's a version that works. (This happens to also be the one I would really recommend if you are going the route with lambda terms at all; this is reasonably efficient.)

```
# it is a very good idea to ensure [uplevel] only gets one argument script
# using [list] to build it is highly recommended and very efficient 
proc LoopBody {startKey endKey anonyProc} {
    for {set i $startKey} {$i < $endKey} {incr i 1} {
        uplevel 1 [list apply $anonyProc $i]
    }
}

proc Complex {} {
    foreach value {100 200 300} {
        LoopBody 10 15 {{x} {
            upvar 1 value value
            puts "x $x value [incr value $x]"
        }}
        puts ""
    }
}
```

The simplest sort of lambda construction is done with a procedure like this:

```
proc lambda {arguments body} {
    set ns [uplevel 1 {namespace current}]
    return [list $arguments $body $ns]
}
```

A more complex version would also generate the `upvar` or capture (read-only copy) for you, but at the same time would be less general. Without that extra complexity (and with `lambda` as above), you get this:

```
proc LoopBody {startKey endKey anonyProc} {
    for {set i $startKey} {$i < $endKey} {incr i 1} {
        uplevel 1 [list apply $anonyProc $i]
    }
}

proc Complex {} {
    foreach value {100 200 300} {
        LoopBody 10 15 [lambda {x} {
            upvar 1 value value
            puts "x $x value [incr value $x]"
        }]
        puts ""
    }
}
```

but there literally isn't any benefit to it here; it is at least as easy to write the literal form.

---

It is very rare for use of `#1` in `upvar`/`uplevel` to be a good idea; it binds to an *absolute* level on the stack. Before coroutines, I'd never seen it. (It makes more sense in coroutines; that level can be treated as a useful place to store coroutine-specific variables.) In your code it is more of a bug waiting to happen.

The *actual* normal way of writing this code would be:

```
proc LoopBody {varName startKey endKey body} {
    upvar 1 $varName i
    for {set i $startKey} {$i < $endKey} {incr i 1} {
        uplevel 1 $body
    } 
}
proc Complex {} {
    foreach value {100 200 300} {
        LoopBody key 10 15 { 
            puts "key $key value [incr value $key]" 
        }
        puts ""
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't discuss Javascript here; it isn't a language I specialize in. All scripts have been tested and found to produce the right output in Tcl 8.6.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and examples. They are very helpful and, although I'll be using the pass-the-body approach, I'm glad to have the additional information about the lambda arguments. I'm not a student but I've been using Ousterhout's and Nadkarni's texts and although Nadkarni provides an example of a lambda proc., it doesn't include the namespace. Perhaps he includes it elsewhere; I was looking only at the section on anonymous procedures (p.40 of over 600; so it could be hiding in there somewhere). I'll add that note to my copy. Thanks again; you've helped me several times now.